# HTML верстка в google app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-forms

Ниже код с моими потугами в работе с  google app script.
Задача следующая, есть таблица с результатами ответов на форму. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OugJLMmrew2El8sqcsOjsGbgYQPgp71tyw141hOnbrI/edit?usp=sharing

Мне необходимо собирать данные каждого опроса и отправлять их письмом.
Часть задачи решает таблица, там формула в ячейках, которая держит значения последнего опроса в статичных верхних ячейках, а ссылки на эти ячейки я указываю в скрипте. 
Мне не хватает верстки html, чтоб можно было оформить письмо, а также игнорировать пустые ячейки не добавлять их в письмо и ячейки с ответом "Да"

Собственно получившаяся у меня портянка, но частично свою задачу выполняет.

```
function sendSelectedEmails() {
  var info = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OugJLMmrew2El8sqcsOjsGbgYQPgp71tyw141hOnbrI");
  var emailAddress = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("bb1").getValue();
  var emailAddress2 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ba2").getValue();
  var subject = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("a2").getValue();
  var m1 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("a2").getValue();
  var m2 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("b2").getValue();
  var m3 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("c2").getValue();
  var m4 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("d2").getValue();
  var m5 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("e2").getValue();
  var m6 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("f2").getValue();
  var m7 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("g2").getValue();
  var m8 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("h2").getValue(); 
  var m9 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("i2").getValue();
  var m10 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("j2").getValue();
  var m11 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("k2").getValue();
  var m12 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("l2").getValue();
  var m13 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("m2").getValue();
  var m14 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("n2").getValue();
  var m15 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("o2").getValue();
  var m16 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("p2").getValue();
  var m17 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("q2").getValue();
  var m18 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("r2").getValue();
  var m19 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("s2").getValue();
  var m20 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("t2").getValue();
  var m21 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("u2").getValue();
  var m22 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("v2").getValue();
  var m23 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("w2").getValue();
  var m24 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("x2").getValue();
  var m25 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("y2").getValue();
  var m26 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("z2").getValue();
  var m27 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("aa2").getValue();
  var m28 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ab2").getValue();
  var m29 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ac2").getValue();
  var m30 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ad2").getValue();
  var m31 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ae2").getValue();
  var m32 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("af2").getValue();
  var m33 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ag2").getValue();
  var m34 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ah2").getValue();
  var m35 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ai2").getValue();
  var m36 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("aj2").getValue();
  var m37 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ak2").getValue();
  var m38 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("al2").getValue();
  var m39 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("am2").getValue();
  var m40 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("an2").getValue();
  var m41 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ao2").getValue();
  var m42 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ap2").getValue();
  var m43 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("aq2").getValue();
  var m44 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ar2").getValue();
  var m45 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("as2").getValue();
  var m46 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("at2").getValue();
  var m47 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("au2").getValue();
  var m48 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("av2").getValue();
  var m49 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("aw2").getValue();
  var m50 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ax2").getValue();
  var m51 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("ay2").getValue();
  var m52 = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("az2").getValue();
  var mall = m1+"\n"+m2+"\n"+m3+"\n"+m4+"\n"+m5+"\n"+m6+"\n"+m7+"\n"+m8+"\n"+m9+"\n"+m10+"\n"+m11+"\n"+m12+"\n"+m13+"\n"+m14+"\n"+m15+"\n"+m16+"\n"+m17+"\n"+m18+"\n"+m18+"\n"+m20+"\n"+m21+"\n"+m22+"\n"+m23+"\n"+m24+"\n"+m25+"\n"+m26+"\n"+m27+"\n"+m28+"\n"+m29+"\n"+m30+"\n"+m31+"\n"+m32+"\n"+m33+"\n"+m34+"\n"+m35+"\n"+m36+"\n"+m37+"\n"+m38+"\n"+m39+"\n"+m40+"\n"+m41+"\n"+m42+"\n"+m43+"\n"+m44+"\n"+m45+"\n"+m46+"\n"+m47+m48+"\n"+m49+"\n"+m50+m51+"\n"+m52;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, mall);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile(subject, mall, MimeType.HTML);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, "фотографии", "в ответном письме прикрепите фотографии");
}
```

Comment: Не понятно на какую часть вопросов отвечать. Как вариант, добавьте условие для отправки https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0772b8a70bc3490f8b43c526e1e4c640#file-gs-L3 вместо "Да" укажите свою проверку.

Comment: А можно ли это условие применить к диапазону? Скажем в диапазоне есть ячейки 30 шт из 30, 15="Да", мы их отсеиваем а остальные собираем в текст и отправляем

Answer (score 1):

Малость поправил код теперь он чуточку аккуратнее. 
Игнорирование ответов "Да" нашел как реализовать в таблице, но тогда код берет пустую ячейку и в письме приходит "`undefined`".

```
function sendSelectedEmails() {
    var info = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OugJLMmrew2El8sqcsOjsGbgYQPgp71tyw141hOnbrI");
    var emailAddress = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("bc1").getValue();
    var subject = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("a2").getValue();
    var range = info.getSheetByName("рассольник").getRange("A2:BA2");
    var data = range.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var text = row[0] + "\n" + row[1] + "\n" + row[2] + "\n" + row[3] + "\n" + row[4] + "\n" + row[5] + "\n" + row[6] + "\n" + row[7] + "\n" + row[8] + "\n" + row[9] + "\n" + row[10] + "\n" + row[11] + "\n" + row[12] + "\n" + row[13] + "\n" + row[14] + "\n" + row[15] + "\n" + row[16] + "\n" + row[17] + "\n" + row[18] + "\n" + row[19] + "\n" + row[20] + "\n" + row[21] + "\n" + row[22] + "\n" + row[23] + "\n" + row[24] + "\n" + row[25] + "\n" + row[26] + "\n" + row[27] + "\n" + row[28] + "\n" + row[29] + "\n" + row[30] + "\n" + row[31] + "\n" + row[32] + "\n" + row[33] + "\n" + row[34] + "\n" + row[35] + "\n" + row[36] + "\n" + row[37] + "\n" + row[38] + "\n" + row[39] + "\n" + row[40] + "\n" + row[41] + "\n" + row[42] + "\n" + row[43] + "\n" + row[44] + "\n" + row[45] + "\n" + row[46] + "\n" + row[47] + "\n" + row[48] + "\n" + row[49] + "\n" + row[50] + "\n" + row[51];
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, text);
    }
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile(subject, text, MimeType.HTML);
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[52], "фотографии", "в ответном письме прикрепите фотографии");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Древний вопрос, но ладно :)
Вероятно, цикл можно было бы еще упростить до такого:

```
var text = '';
for (i in data) {
    for (var j in data[i]) {
        if (data[i][j] !== undefined) {
            text += data[i][j] + '\n';
        }
    }
}
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, text);
```